# sometimes evince takes a lot of time to open a file

Tags: evince

Sometimes evince takes several seconds to open a pdf that otherwise opens in 1 or 2 secs. Any ideas about a fix or troubleshooting procedure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run evince from the command prompt using strace like this:

```
strace evince /path/to/file.pdf
```

while looking at the output of strace at the terminal I noticed that it was pausing for a couple of seconds at a line like this:

```
stat(..."/path/to/a/file/I/opened/a/few/days/ago"...)
```

This pause occurred a few times. I also noticed that "/path/to/a/file/I/opened/a/few/days/ago" was on a network share that was not available at the moment (it was a NAS that was powered of) but my Linux box still had the share mounted and busy. I've umount -l the share and evince started normally. I don't know why evince was stat'ing that old file but this was the root of my problems.